# More than one ManagedBy entity on an Active Directory group

Tags: c#, active-directory, exchange-server, directorysearcher

Is it possible to have more than one entity/person listed as a manager of an AD group?

I have a distribution group created using Exchange. The group has multiple `ManagedBy` entities when viewed from the Exchange side.

When I query using `DirectorySearcher` AD only shows just one entry for `ManagedBy`, the first entry.

I can update the `ManagedBy` with a string value of a known user but using something like the below doesn't seem to work.

Code snippet A:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, _connection.Domain, _connection.ServiceUserName, _connection.ServicePassword))
{
    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher())
    {
        var sp = new GroupSearchPrincipal(context, groupDn);
        searcher.QueryFilter = sp;

        var groupSearch = searcher.FindOne();

        if (groupSearch is null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"The Group with SamAccountName {groupDn} could not be found");
        }

        var directoryEntry = (DirectoryEntry)groupSearch.GetUnderlyingObject();

        directoryEntry.Properties["managedBy"].Add(managerDn);

        directoryEntry.CommitChanges();
        directoryEntry.Close();
    }

    return SuccessResponse();
}
```

Committing the change yields the result shown in this screenshot:

[image: Error Saving Changes]

The error possibly means that I'm adding a value that already exists with the included new value from 'managerDn'. Clearing the value seems to confirm this.

```
directoryEntry.Properties["managedBy"].Clear();
```

Are multiple `managedBy` entries exclusive to Exchange?

Comment: If you look at the [`managedBy` attribute's declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-managedby) - it specifies `Is-Single-Valued = True` - so I guess in "basic" AD, it contains only a single value

Answer (score 3):

If the group was created with Exchange it'll likely contain the attribute

`msExchCoManagedByLink`

This identifies the additional ManagedBy entities I was looking for.